# Why does Chrome say I'm offline whenever I have my DevTools open?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Something weird is happening with Google Chrome. I open any site, doesn't matter if I open google.com or just any development I'm working on. At first, it works perfectly fine, but if I open the developer tools, by either pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> or right-clicking on any element to inspect it, the page won't load again, telling me that there is no connections (dinosaur included).

No matter how many times I press F5 to reload the site, if the developer tools are open, it simply won't reload the page. But if I close the tools (not the browser, it remains open) and press F5 again, the page reloads perfectly.

I've tried it with Edge and it works without a problem, developer tools or not.

There is no code involved here. As I said, doesn't matter if it's a local site I'm creating or any public site like Google, Facebook, you name it. The behaviour is the same.

Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: I think a better place to ask this question would be Ask Youbuntube.

Comment: Also, this is not a programming question.

Comment: Well, it's been happening while I've been coding, so my default went to StackOverflow. Yes, I did mention public websites, but that's just tests I made. I'll go somewhere else to ask. (Second time I've gotten no answer here.)

Comment: We allow questions about "_[software tools commonly used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_" here, so this question is fine.

Comment: Do you by any chance enabled throttling in the network tab? (Small dropdown near the top of the tab.)

Comment: I just turned on "disable cache" in that tab, and turning on and off "offline" in the application tab to test the service worker for a PWA.

Comment: @Ivar, thanks, I looked around the network tab and saw an option hidden in a combobox that allowed me to set it to "no throttling". That fixed the issue. Don't know when I changed it, though. Perhaps a hot key or shortcut I pressed without knowing? Thanks a lot again.

Comment: FTR: This is not exactly a programming-related Q, but I already answered it a few years ago here - https://superuser.com/questions/988941/err-internet-disconnected-whenever-attempting-to-load-page-with-developer-tools/990584

Please accept @Ivar s answer if it helped your problem though...

Answer (score 29):

You likely have enabled throttling.

This feature can be used to simulate different network situations/environments to test how the webpage reacts to it. It is only active when the Developer Tools are open, which explains why you only experience this issue in that situation.

To fix it, simply select "No throttling" from the throttling dropdown in the Network tab.

[image: Image of the Chrome Developer Tools Network tab with the throttling dropdown]